# Create R code in LaTeX which can be directly copied and executed in R

Tags: listings, r, code

I would like to create R code in a latex document, which is directly executable, when copied into an R environment. I use the following MWE, but the `<-` and the `*` can't be properly interpreted by R. Is there any way to tell LaTeX to use different symbols in this case, which can then be directly used in R. It's just a short example to give students an option to try out R so I can't expect any knowledge of R and thus it should be pretty easy to execute.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,automark]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R,inputencoding={utf8},extendedchars=false, escapeinside={(*}{*)}]

 A <- matrix(c(0.15, 0.01, 0,
               0.14, 0.36, 0.07,
               0.15, 0.13, 0.3), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
 I = diag(nrow = nrow(A))

 I%*%A
 I  %(*$\ast$*)% A
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, it can be done by directly using the correct unicode symbol, i.e. `%(*\symbol{"002A}*)%` and `(*\symbol{"002D}*)` work as expected.

Comment: Could you write it as an answer. Answering your own question is fine here. [Can I answer my own question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) -> yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me at least, using `minted` gives a PDF where copied code works. `minted` uses `pygments` to do the actual highlighting, so you have to compile with `shell-escape` enabled, e.g. `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`. With the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,automark]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{R}

 A <- matrix(c(0.15, 0.01, 0,
               0.14, 0.36, 0.07,
               0.15, 0.13, 0.3), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
 I = diag(nrow = nrow(A))

 I%*%A
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I get the output

[image: PDF output]

Copying from the PDF to a console in RStudio, I get the following console output:

```
> 
> A <- matrix(c(0.15, 0.01, 0,
+               0.14, 0.36, 0.07,
+               0.15, 0.13, 0.3), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> I = diag(nrow = nrow(A))
> I%*%A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.15 0.01 0.00
[2,] 0.14 0.36 0.07
[3,] 0.15 0.13 0.30
> 
>
```

Comment: Works really nice, much easier than looking up the unicode symbols. Although I had to use `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I just add the comment as an answer. It can be done by directly using the correct unicode symbol, i.e. `%(*\symbol{"002A}*)%` and `(*\symbol{"002D}*)` work as expected.